# Is it possible to run node.js project without npm start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, powerbi, web-component

PowerBI has a sample code for a NodeJS program, I can only access the PowerBI interface when I use the command to run the NodeJS project. Now I would like to create a web component for the PowerBI interface and create a customized HTML tag like `<powerbi-report>` `</powerbi-report>`. The PowerBI can only be used when the command `npm start` is running. Is that possible to make a whole Nodejs file as web-component? Just put every .js file together, and running the project without `npm start`? I was wondering if someone can provide some useful links about how to make a whole node.js project to be a web component.

**The PowerBI interface looks like the screen-shot below:**
[image]

Comment: How about a link to that sample code? It is likely that `npm start` is running a server - if that's the case you cannot create a web component from that sample.

Comment: `npm start` is likely defined in `package.json`, maybe post that

Comment: Yeah, I can only access PowerBI only the server is running

Answer (score -1):

You could use [esbuild](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild). It's an extremely fast JavaScript bundler and minifier

Comment: May I ask you how this one work?